# How would the first brew taste like ? If it goes well , and if it doesnt go well?

Tags: beer, off-flavor, first-time-brewer

Out of curiosity, i just wanted to know how a home brew made of bakers yeast , good water(almost sweet) and barley malt taste like . would it be sweet or flat or fizzy or something else?

At the same time , how would it taste or smell like its bad ?Is it safe to drink if its bad ? I would like to know from experiences from most of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you can use baker's yeast, but I doubt you'd be as happy as you would by using brewer's yeast.  Both yeasts are Saccharomyces cerevisiae, however, they are different strains of the same species that are bred to do two different jobs.  Baker's yeast has been bred to produce CO2 and cause bread to rise and brewer's yeast has been bred to survive in a high alcohol/high sugar environment and produce alcohol.  That said, it will work, but you'd likely have some off flavors from being outside the temperature window. Most typically this would be DMS which would give you a "corn" taste and smell.

The yeast that brewers use has been cultivated to convert the sugar into alcohol and not produce any off flavors.  Being new to the homebrew experience, I have concerns that you don't have the equipment to maintain the temperature window for this yeast (heck, I'm not entirely sure what the window is for baker's yeast) or how much to use for a 5 gallon (19 liter) batch.

That said, if you only used yeast (for the sake of argument, we won't worry about what kind), water and malt, your beer would be very sweet.  The proper term for this style is called a Gruit.  You'll need something to bring some bitterness to the table.  Most of us use hops for this.  You'll see recipes with a hop schedule that lists hop additions at 60 minutes (left in the boil) for bittering, 30 minutes for flavoring and 5 minutes for aroma.

I am also concerned with how you'd plan on fermenting this (based on previous questions).  Remember, beer should be fermented in a closed environment that will allow CO2 gas to escape while preventing Oxygen from entering your beer.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't be Gruit without any kind of bittering herbs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention hops.  Without those, it will be sickly sweet.

Comment: Or some bittering agent.  It doesn't have to be done with hops.  It could be done with other herbs, but I wouldn't use anything funky in the first few brews.

Comment: Also, I strongly suspect baker's yeast won't drop out of suspension as readily as a well-bred brewer's yeast, since that isn't a consideration in cultivating baker's strains.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience it will be sweet and fizzy in taste.